# Mat-Select Dropdown Opening Wrong Way

Tags: angular, angular-material

Is there a way to force this dropdown to open towards the bottom no matter what and expand the page if necessary?

[image: result]

Not really sure if minimum code example would help much here as it has to do more with positioning on the page

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, that sounds like a really bad user experience and personally I would hate to navigate a page which does this, whether it's on mobile or desktop.

As per [material guidelines regarding menus](https://m2.material.io/components/menus#usage) (and dropdown is a special case of a menu), that is the only correct behavior for material components:

> Menus should be positioned relative to the edge of the screen or
> browser. They typically appear next to (or in front of) the element
> that generates them. If they are in a position to be cut off by the
> browser or screen’s edge, the menu can instead appear to the left,
> right, or above the element that generates it.

Which is probably why Angular Material team didn't expose the `PositionStrategy` as an input (or any other way, i.e. from DI) in the first place. There is an outstanding git issue for that [here](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/22493), but so far it seems like it's a low prio one.

So you're out of luck when it comes to changing the behavior of `mat-select` itself. At this point your best bet would be to re-create it as a custom component, which would open a CDK [overlay](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview) on click of the trigger and then create a custom `PositionStrategy` that would match your requirements when it comes to placement and it's behavior.

Comment: what if instead of expanding the page, the dropdown is scrollable, even then depending on the option selected, mat-select will open upwards or downwards based on the current item selected in a way that's really unappealing to me